# Insert/Display HTML through ckEditor into SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, repeater

I am trying to integrate CKEditor into my webpage which was successful. Please how do I get HTML to be inserted into the database and get them output to the screen in formatted way.

This is the frontend for inserting my text

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="txtDescription" BasePath="../../../ckeditor/" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
</CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

This is the backend for inserting my text

```
string sql1 = "INSERT INTO dbo.Blog (Description) " +
              "VALUES (@Description)";

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
con.Open();

string str1 = Server.HtmlDecode(vDescription);
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NText).Value = str1;
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

This is the frontend for displaying my text

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("Description") %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But I am still getting the html codes displayed in my display page...
like this :

```
<p>This is the text that was displayed</p>
```

NOTE : I would be displaying output inside repeater

Comment: How are you getting value from `txtDescription` and/or assigning the value to `vDescription`?

Comment: UpdateRecordWithImage(txtDescription.Text);                                               UpdateRecordWithImage(string vDescription.Text) {                                    }